# Direct carrier billing - How to get answer from SHORT CODES?

Tags: php, sms, billing

I have created one auction system that will allow users to post/ list their products , but we want to implement "Direct carrier billing" API , but all API's that i have searched into google none of them support our country, some supports but only for a small amount for 1 euro.. So our packages will have different amounts and more than 1 euro , for example 3 euro 5 euro etc..

Our system will generate Post id and will show instruction to user how to pay it for example " Send a sms to "55585" ( Short code ) with text "84547" this "84547" is post id that will be treated as premium after payment.. so the user will send the sms manually..

But after the user send SMS to this short code, HOW to get answer from short code if they paid successful or fail? is there any way that we can listen to answers using PHP or any other tool?

Comment: you don't get an answer from a "short code". you get an answer from an SMS system, which happens to have a shortcode as its address.

Comment: yeah, but how to get that answer direct to web app and treat it automatically ?